# How to prove that $\sin(\sqrt{x})$ is not periodic?

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove that $\sin(\sqrt{x})$ is not periodic?
THe definition of a periodic function is $f(x+P)=f(x)$.

So I assume that $\sin(\sqrt{x+P})=\sin(\sqrt{x})$. This is equivalent to $\sin(\sqrt{x+P})-\sin(\sqrt{x})=0$. This implies $2cos(\frac{\sqrt{x+P}+\sqrt{x}}{2})\sin(\frac{\sqrt{x+P}-\sqrt{x}}{2})$. What should I do next?

Comment: Hint:  If it were periodic, its derivative would be as well.

Comment: So I have to prove that $\frac{cos(\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}}$ is non periodic as well? How could I do that?

Comment: It's really clear that that function is non-periodic.  What happens as $x\to \infty$?

Comment: Worth noting:  your attempt doesn't really make sense.  Why should $\sin (\sqrt {x+P})=\sin (x)$?  Periodicity would mean $\sin (\sqrt {x+P})=\sin (\sqrt x)$.

Comment: Typo, I am sorry, I am not adept at using Latex yet.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your answer, lulu?

Comment: Please show some effort.  As I said, it is extremely clear that the derivative is non-periodic.  It has a limit as $x$ goes to infinity!  No non-constant periodic function can take a limit at infinity.

Comment: Well, note that if $f(x)$ is periodic on the domain $D$ then if $x\in D\iff x+P\in D$. This means that if $x\in D$ then $x-P\in D$, but this is not true in our case. ($x=0$).

Comment: Note that when $\sqrt x = 2\pi$ then $\cos {\sqrt x} =1$.  This is the greatest value $\cos{\sqrt x}$ can be.  And $\frac {\cos{\sqrt x}}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac 1{2\pi}$.  For any larger $x$ then $\frac 1{\sqrt{x}} < \frac 1{2\pi}$ and $\cos{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt x} \le \frac 1{\sqrt{s}} < \frac 1{2\pi}$.  So at $x = 4\pi^2$ then $\cos{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt x}$ a certain size and it will *never* be that large again.  It can't be periodic if it will never be that value again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$\sin(\sqrt{x+P})=\sin(\sqrt{x})$$

$$\implies \sqrt{x+P}=\sqrt{x}+2k\pi  \text { or }\sqrt {x+P}=2k\pi+ \pi - \sqrt{x} $$

Upon squaring we get  $$ x+P = x+4 k^2\pi ^2 +4k\pi \sqrt x $$

or $$x+P =((2k+1) \pi) ^2 + x-2(2k+1)\pi \sqrt x$$

Note that neither of the above holds for a constant $P$ and every $x$

Comment: I understand your proof except for $\pi-\sqrt{x}$ part.

Comment: two angles have the same sines if either the difference is $2k\pi$ or one is $\pi$  minus  the other.

Comment: $\sin(\sqrt{x+P})=\sin(\sqrt{x})$ implies $\sqrt{x+P}=\sqrt{x}+2k\pi $ or $\sqrt {x+P}= (2k+1)\pi - \sqrt{x}$, for some integer $k$ which may **depend on $x$**.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sin {\sqrt x}$ is period with period $P$ then so is $\cos {\sqrt x}$ because $\cos {\sqrt x} = \sqrt {1 - \sin^2 \sqrt x}=\sqrt {1 - \sin^2 \sqrt {x+P}}=\cos (\sqrt{x+P})$.  Likewis so is the derivative of $\sin {\sqrt x}$ because $ \lim \frac {\sin (\sqrt {x + h}) -\sin(\sqrt{x})}h=  \lim \frac {\sin (\sqrt {x +P + h}) -\sin(\sqrt{x+P})}h$.

But the derivative of $\sin (\sqrt{x})$ is $\frac{cos(\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}}$ and if $\cos (\sqrt{x + P}) = \cos (\sqrt{x})$ then $\frac{cos(\sqrt{x+P})}{2\sqrt{x+P}}=\frac{cos(\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x+P}} \ne \frac{cos(\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}}$

This is a contradiction.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\cos {\sqrt x} = \pm \sqrt {1 - \sin^2 \sqrt x}$? Btw, a possible duplicate (with an answer using the derivative) was already pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the domain $D$ of a $P$-periodic function $f$ must be "invariant by translations of $P$", i.e.: $D+P=D$. In this case $\forall P>0, \ D+P$ is a proprer subset of $D$ hence $f(x)$ can not be a periodic function.